# How to fix Symfony v2.8 "Creating/Configuring Services in the Container" 'autoloader expected class ...' error

Tags: php, service, symfony-2.8

For quite a while I've been trying to understand how to add my own library of functions that I want to use in my Web-App's different controller/bundles, but I just found that I needed to 'house' these functions a Symfony Service Container.

Unlike other computer languages, Services, are not a background process!

To get a better handle on this, I tried out the example in the Symfony v2.8 guide section on [Creating/Configuring Services in the Container](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container).  I created the following file in the suggested directory:

```
<?php  // <=== This was missing from the MessageGenerator.php file!
       //
       // Adding it to the file solved the autoloader error, and now the MessageGenerator
       // class loads properly!
       //

// src/AppBundle/Service/MessageGenerator.php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

class MessageGenerator {
    public function getHappyMessage() {
        $messages = [
            'You did it! You updated the system! Amazing!',
            'That was one of the coolest updates I\'ve seen all day!',
            'Great work! Keep going!'
        ];

        $index = array_rand($messages);

        return $messages[$index];
    }
}
```

Then I added the following to the services configuration file:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.message_generator:
        class:     AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator
        arguments: []
```

And then I placed the following lines in a controller/bundle that otherwise was previously working:

```
$messageGenerator = $this->container->get( 'app.message_generator' );
$generatedMessage = $messageGenerator->getHappyMessage();
```

When I uploaded these files and ran the associated web-page, I got:

```
The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Service\MessageGenerator" to be defined in
file "/var/www/vhosts/symfony2/vendor/composer/../../src/AppBundle/Service/
MessageGenerator.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name
or namespace probably has a typo.
```

This message appears to be saying that the MessageGenerator.php file was found in the src/AppBundle/Service directory.  However the class MessageGenerator was not defined in the MessageGenerator.php file because the file wasn't recognised as a php file due to the missing

Answer (score 0):

The MessageGenerator.php file was missing

```
$messageGenerator = $this->container->get( 'app.message_generator' );
$generatedMessage = $messageGenerator->getHappyMessage();
```

lines were executed, and $generatedMessage contained one of the array element messages, as expected.